# Unable to pass parameter through onclick event using jquery

Tags: jquery

When I am running the following script and code it is running fine.

```
    <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog(
                    {
                        autoOpen: false
                    });
                $("#btnOpen").on("click", function () {
                    $("#dialog").load("../Master/reportspage.aspx");
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                });
            });
        </script>

    <div id="dialog" title="Sales Master" ></div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btnOpen" />
```

But I am unable to pass parameter in btnOpen. Like

```
    <div id="dialog" title="Sales Master" >
    </div>
<button id="btnSlMster"  onclick="btnOpen('../Master/reportspage.aspx')"><span>Sales</span></button>
```

How can I pass parameter in button onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, you cannot pass parameters to the anonymous event handler functions which are bound unobtrusively.

The most effective way to do what you require is to put the value you want to use in the event handler in to a `data` attribute. You can then read this value from the DOM when the event occurs, like this:

```html
<div id="dialog" title="Sales Master"></div>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="btnOpen" data-url="../Master/reportspage.aspx" />
```

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false
  });
  
  $("#btnOpen").on("click", function() {
    $dialog.load($(this).data('url')).dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Mentioned script is working fine. But when I am using it in button it is not working.

<button id="btnSlMster"  onclick="btnOpen" data-url="../Master/reportspage.aspx"><span>Sales</span></button>

Comment: Remove the `onclick="btnOpen"` attribute. Also the `id` is different there, so remember to update the jQuery selector

Comment: Thanks. Had tried it is not working.
````
<button id="btnOpen"   data-url="../Master/reportspage.aspx"><span>Sales</span></button>
````
Actualy in my page multiple buttons I am using. On clickink the button it will populate the different aspx page in dialog box.
How can I do that?

Comment: Your code should be doing that as it is. 'in my page multiple buttons I am using' - given that statement, ensure that all the buttons have different `id` on them. You cannot re-use the same one